# How to run an instance of Excel Online on my own domain?

Tags: excel, office365, excel-online

I stumbled on this website and found it very interesting because I'm trying to do the same thing: run Excel Online on my own domain. I tried Googling around without success. Does anyone have a resource or approach to this problem (see image for more information*) ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need to Configure your Online Office Server:

[Configure Office Online Server for SharePoint Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/configure-office-online-server-for-sharepoint-server-2016/configure-office-online-server-for-sharepoint-server-2016)

Answer (score 0):

They may be using one of the following: [CSPP](https://dev.office.com/programs/officecloudstorage) or using their [own domain](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-domain-and-users-to-Office-365-6383f56d-3d09-4dcb-9b41-b5f5a5efd611?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).